# Communication Between Views Using ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: ios, uiview, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to understand who Reactive Cocoa works... There's not many documentation or examples above that Framework. I need to use it to send signals between different views. In my view, I have a table and another viewcontroller, and I need, that when some cell is selected, send a signal to the other viewcontroller... How can I send signals between different views using Reactive Cocoa? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use RACSubject/RACReplaySubject and send values using sendNext and subscribe to it in other place
or
just pass objective-c block to other view controller and call it there - it acts like callback and can do something in parent view controller.
It depends what you need to do exactly.